# crypto_box_keypair() in ios while using Encryption

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, encryption

I have to generate a keypair using using crypto_box_keypair() or decode a hex string to a

byte array so that you have a 'public key' byte array and also a 'secret key'.

Call crypto_box(m,n,pk,sk) where m is the string, n is the nonce, pk is the public key, and

sk is the secret key.

It is requirement of client.

Any help, since i am new to Encryption??